# Difference between two types of List initialization in Dart

Tags: list, dart

I can not seem to grasp these two kinds of List initialization. Here is the code:

```
class foo {
  int x;
  double y;
}

void main() {
  final a = List<foo>();

  List<foo> b;

  print(a.runtimeType);
  print(b.runtimeType);
}
```

What is the difference between a and b here ? Also a.runtimetype shows JsonArray but b.runtimetype shows Null. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are the same, except that the first one is initialized, and the second one is not.

As [the doc](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#default-value) says:

> Uninitialized variables have an initial value of null. Even variables with numeric types are initially null, because numbers—like everything else in Dart—are objects.

So any var not initialized will implicitly have a null value, as we know, null in Dart is also an object of type `Null`.

```dart
void main() {
  String c;
  int d;
  Symbol e;
  print(c.runtimeType);
  print(d.runtimeType);
  print(e.runtimeType);
}
```

All `runtimeType`s above will print `Null`. And if you initialize properly your `b` variable, it will equally print `JSArray<foo>`.

```dart
void main() {
  final a = List<foo>() ;
  List<foo> b = [foo()];

  print(a.runtimeType); 
  print(b.runtimeType); 
}
```

About the `JSArray<foo>` printed, you're probably running it on DartPad or as a web application, in which Dart is compiled to JS. If you run it locally as a server-side or client app, it would print `List<foo>`.